# How can I dynamically change the meta data of a MEAN.JS application before it loads the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

Using the MEAN.JS framework, I am trying to dynamically change a page's meta data by modifying the app.locals variables in the app/config/express.js file. Does anyone have experience with trying to do this?

If it's an inner page being requested such as /t/elonmusk, I want to include the path (elonmusk) in the meta title and have a different title if they are requesting the home page. I tried simply using an if statement on req.url in the app.use function but this will not work because it sends the home page request ('/') after requesting '/t/elonmusk'. I can't find a way to see the original url that is being requested by the server.

Is there a better way to modify the meta data server side?

Edit: I'm using URL rerouting to remove the hashbang so the actual full URL is indeed being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since the part of URL after # in your case /t/elonmusk is not send to the server, there's no way you could do this server-side, however , you can change the title on the client once the page loads.

Comment: I should have clarified. The URL actually is being sent to the servers because I'm using rerouting to remove the hashbang. See this [link](http://followfly.co/t/elonmusk) as an example. I got a solution working working. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by storing the previous URL in a variable. If the current URL is '/' and previous URL contains '/t/' then I know an inner page is being loaded and can then update the meta data appropriately.